# TinyMce 4 Dynamicly add a button to toolbar after init

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am working in an LMS that allows me to run Javascript on the page. But not edit the TinyMce init script.

Is it possible to add a custom button to the tinymce toolbar after init.
As I understand something like this should work but it doesn't give an error and it doesnt add the button.

```html
ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor

// Register example button
ed.addButton('example', {
    title : 'example.desc',
    cmd : 'mceExample',
    image : 'http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-20-20-1.jpg'
});
```

Any help is appreciated.